gRPC Invalid content-type value: text/html when upgrading to .NET 8
I am working on upgrading the solution from .NET 7 to .NET 8. Identical code works on .NET 7, but on .NET 8 I start getting exceptions on client side:
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Invalid content-type value: text/html; charset=utf-8")'

When debugging, request never reaches gRPC server.
I have not set content-type anywhere explicitly. Anyone dealt with this issue before?
I can provide more details if required.
Edit:
It appears that the issue is in [Authorization] attribute. It seems to be connected to MediatR upgrade from 11.1.0 to any higher version. I use MediatR to add authorization data before sending gRPC request.
